# How could I remove "My Mac" from targets list?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have "my Mac" showing up above my ios device and a boatload of simulators.
the app and the framework that manifests that infuriating behavior is
for ios only.

How can I get rid of that nonsensical device in the xcode dropdown?

PS "My mac" shows up immediately upon opening the project in xcode 9.2
the rest of the options (including Generic iOS device) become available
a few seconds afterwards.

Comment: Is your base SDK macOS and not iOS?

Comment: it's an ios sdk (framework) and ios app

Comment: I'm talking about your target's base SDK. It's under build settings -> architecture

Comment: it's Latest iOS (iOS 11.2)